# drush not able to download and enable modules whenever executing drush en <module_name>

Tags: command-line-interface, drupal-8, drush

I keep getting this pop-up screen that tries to locate an app to open .launcher files whenever I try to execute `drush en <Module_Name>` commands to download and enable a module on Drupal 8. On mac nothing like this happens, I'm not sure what needs to be done in order for the commands to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use composer to install module : composer require drupal/migrate_tools